# Problema con el armado de SVG animado

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, animación

Estoy teniendo un problemas con la animación izquierda que no me funciona y con el tamaño que no me esta aplicando como el de al lado. ¿Por qué puede ser?

```css
 body{
  padding: 40px;
  margin: 0;
 }
 .container{
     width: 1170px;
     margin: auto;

     height: 391px;
 }
 .col{
  height: 250px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(112, 198, 171, 0.7) 0%, rgba(70, 166, 195, 0.7) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(112, 198, 171, 0.7)), color-stop(100%, rgba(70, 166, 195, 0.7)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(112, 198, 171, 0.7) 0%, rgba(70, 166, 195, 0.7) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(112, 198, 171, 0.7) 0%, rgba(70, 166, 195, 0.7) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(112, 198, 171, 0.7) 0%, rgba(70, 166, 195, 0.7) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(112, 198, 171, 0.7) 0%, rgba(70, 166, 195, 0.7) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cc70c6ab', endColorstr='#cc46a6c3',GradientType=1 ); width: 48%; 
    margin: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
 -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 20px;
 -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0;
 border-radius: 20px;
 border-top-left-radius: 0;
    float: left; 
    box-shadow: 0 2px 18px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.21);
 }
 .col h2{
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-top: 12%;
  font-size: 24px;
 }
 svg{
  padding: 40px 20px 40px 40px;
     margin: auto;
     display: block;
 
 }
 .path {
    stroke-dasharray: 1000;
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
    animation: dash 5s linear alternate infinite;
 }

 @keyframes dash {
   from {
     stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
   }
   to {
     stroke-dashoffset: 0;
   }
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="col">
  <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
    width="121px" height="122px" viewBox="0 0 121 122" enable-background="new 0 0 121 122" xml:space="preserve" style="float:left">
  <path fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M60.783,2.302
   C28.722,2.302,2.73,28.294,2.73,60.355c0,32.063,25.992,58.054,58.053,58.054c32.063,0,58.054-25.991,58.054-58.054
   C118.837,28.294,92.846,2.302,60.783,2.302L60.783,2.302z"/>
  <g>
   <path class="path" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M42.073,56.853c-4.032,0-7.313-3.281-7.313-7.312
    c0-4.033,3.28-7.313,7.313-7.313c4.031,0,7.312,3.281,7.312,7.313C49.385,53.572,46.104,56.853,42.073,56.853z"/>
   <path class="path" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M42.073,75.667c-2.622,0-4.755-2.215-4.755-4.939
    v-2.796c-1.718-0.442-3.354-1.12-4.883-2.025l-1.979,1.98c-0.956,0.954-2.214,1.481-3.546,1.481c-1.262,0-2.436-0.481-3.307-1.352
    c-1.854-1.854-1.795-4.928,0.13-6.854l1.978-1.979c-0.905-1.531-1.585-3.167-2.027-4.884h-2.794c-2.722,0-4.938-2.132-4.938-4.753
    s2.216-4.753,4.938-4.753h2.793c0.442-1.718,1.121-3.355,2.024-4.887l-1.974-1.975c-1.925-1.925-1.984-4.998-0.131-6.853
    c0.873-0.872,2.047-1.351,3.308-1.351c1.312,0,2.604,0.54,3.546,1.481l1.973,1.974c1.532-0.906,3.17-1.586,4.89-2.028v-2.789
    c0-2.723,2.134-4.938,4.755-4.938c2.621,0,4.753,2.216,4.753,4.938v2.789c1.72,0.442,3.358,1.122,4.888,2.027l1.973-1.973
    c0.958-0.957,2.216-1.481,3.549-1.481c1.261,0,2.435,0.479,3.305,1.35c1.854,1.855,1.792,4.928-0.13,6.854l-1.975,1.975
    c0.905,1.533,1.583,3.169,2.024,4.887h2.793c2.723,0,4.939,2.132,4.939,4.753S65.979,54.3,63.255,54.3h-2.793
    c-0.444,1.718-1.122,3.354-2.027,4.885l1.976,1.978c1.927,1.924,1.984,4.999,0.132,6.854c-0.873,0.87-2.046,1.352-3.307,1.352
    c-1.332,0-2.591-0.527-3.548-1.481l-1.98-1.98c-1.529,0.905-3.167,1.581-4.881,2.023v2.8
    C46.827,73.452,44.694,75.667,42.073,75.667z"/>
   <path class="path" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M85.728,84.026c-3.659,0-6.638-2.979-6.638-6.639
    c0-3.658,2.977-6.637,6.638-6.637c3.66,0,6.637,2.979,6.637,6.637C92.364,81.048,89.386,84.026,85.728,84.026z"/>
   <path class="path" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M85.728,97.283c-2.135,0-3.872-1.798-3.872-4.009
    v-1.862c-1.155-0.318-2.261-0.775-3.306-1.37l-1.315,1.315c-0.776,0.775-1.797,1.204-2.878,1.204c-1.027,0-1.986-0.393-2.696-1.105
    c-1.508-1.51-1.466-4.009,0.097-5.57l1.317-1.32c-0.594-1.041-1.053-2.148-1.371-3.304h-1.857c-2.212,0-4.01-1.737-4.01-3.871
    s1.798-3.872,4.01-3.872h1.855c0.32-1.155,0.777-2.263,1.371-3.307l-1.315-1.315c-1.563-1.563-1.604-4.062-0.099-5.571
    c0.712-0.714,1.672-1.105,2.699-1.105c1.08,0,2.102,0.428,2.877,1.2l1.312,1.313c1.045-0.594,2.152-1.054,3.308-1.37v-1.855
    c0-2.21,1.739-4.009,3.873-4.009s3.871,1.799,3.871,4.009v1.855c1.156,0.318,2.265,0.776,3.307,1.37l1.313-1.313
    c0.775-0.773,1.796-1.2,2.878-1.2c1.026,0,1.984,0.392,2.695,1.104c1.509,1.511,1.466,4.009-0.098,5.573L98.38,70.21
    c0.594,1.043,1.054,2.15,1.37,3.307h1.856c2.212,0,4.01,1.738,4.01,3.871c0,2.136-1.799,3.874-4.01,3.874h-1.858
    c-0.318,1.154-0.776,2.261-1.371,3.304l1.316,1.315c1.564,1.566,1.606,4.065,0.098,5.573c-0.711,0.713-1.669,1.105-2.696,1.105
    c-1.08,0-2.104-0.428-2.877-1.202L92.9,90.04c-1.044,0.594-2.148,1.052-3.303,1.369v1.863
    C89.599,95.485,87.86,97.283,85.728,97.283z"/>
   <path class="path" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
    M30.104,48.726c0,0,0.794-11.238,11.309-10.909"/>
  </g>
  <h2>Geolocalización 1.0 0</h2>
  </svg>

 </div> 
 <div class="col">
  <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
    width="121px" height="122px" viewBox="0 0 121 122" enable-background="new 0 0 121 122" xml:space="preserve" style="float:left">
  <path class="path" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M60.783,2.302
   C28.722,2.302,2.73,28.294,2.73,60.355c0,32.063,25.992,58.054,58.053,58.054c32.063,0,58.054-25.991,58.054-58.054
   C118.837,28.294,92.846,2.302,60.783,2.302L60.783,2.302z"/>
  <g>
   <path class="path" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M85.754,45.762H35.813
    c-2.115,0-3.676-0.538-4.77-1.644c-1.849-1.869-1.818-4.723-1.783-8.027c0.006-0.454,0.01-0.918,0.01-1.392
    c0-0.474-0.004-0.938-0.01-1.391c-0.035-3.305-0.065-6.159,1.783-8.027c1.094-1.106,2.654-1.645,4.77-1.645h49.941
    c2.115,0,3.676,0.538,4.771,1.645c1.849,1.868,1.816,4.722,1.781,8.027c-0.006,0.454-0.01,0.918-0.01,1.391
    c0,0.473,0.004,0.938,0.01,1.392c0.035,3.304,0.065,6.158-1.781,8.027C89.43,45.224,87.869,45.762,85.754,45.762z"/>
   <path class="path" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M85.754,71.651H35.813
    c-2.115,0-3.676-0.537-4.77-1.645c-1.849-1.869-1.818-4.725-1.783-8.025c0.006-0.455,0.01-0.92,0.01-1.393
    c0-0.475-0.004-0.938-0.01-1.394c-0.035-3.304-0.065-6.158,1.783-8.027c1.094-1.106,2.654-1.644,4.77-1.644h49.941
    c2.115,0,3.676,0.538,4.771,1.644c1.849,1.869,1.816,4.723,1.781,8.027c-0.006,0.454-0.01,0.918-0.01,1.394
    c0,0.473,0.004,0.938,0.01,1.393c0.035,3.303,0.065,6.156-1.781,8.025C89.43,71.114,87.869,71.651,85.754,71.651z"/>
   <path class="path" fill="#fff" d="M69.284,61.12c0,0.646-0.524,1.172-1.17,1.172H62.69c-0.646,0-1.171-0.522-1.171-1.172l0,0
    c0-0.646,0.525-1.169,1.171-1.169h5.424C68.762,59.951,69.284,60.476,69.284,61.12L69.284,61.12z"/>
   <path class="path" fill="#fff" d="M74.021,63.834c-0.646,0-1.172-0.366-1.172-0.817v-3.79c0-0.451,0.522-0.818,1.172-0.818l0,0
    c0.646,0,1.169,0.367,1.169,0.818v3.79C75.189,63.469,74.665,63.834,74.021,63.834L74.021,63.834z"/>
   <path class="path" fill="#fff" d="M86.198,61.12c0,0.646-0.524,1.172-1.17,1.172h-5.424c-0.646,0-1.171-0.522-1.171-1.172l0,0
    c0-0.646,0.525-1.169,1.171-1.169h5.424C85.676,59.951,86.198,60.476,86.198,61.12L86.198,61.12z"/>
   <path class="path" fill="#fff" d="M69.284,87.245c0,0.646-0.524,1.172-1.17,1.172H62.69c-0.646,0-1.171-0.522-1.171-1.172l0,0c0-0.646,0.525-1.17,1.171-1.17
    h5.424C68.762,86.075,69.284,86.601,69.284,87.245L69.284,87.245z"/>
   <path class="path" fill="#fff" d="M74.021,89.959c-0.646,0-1.172-0.366-1.172-0.817v-3.789c0-0.451,0.522-0.818,1.172-0.818l0,0
    c0.646,0,1.169,0.367,1.169,0.818v3.789C75.189,89.594,74.665,89.959,74.021,89.959L74.021,89.959z"/>
   <path class="path" fill="#fff" d="M86.198,87.245c0,0.646-0.524,1.172-1.17,1.172h-5.424c-0.646,0-1.171-0.522-1.171-1.172l0,0
    c0-0.646,0.525-1.17,1.171-1.17h5.424C85.676,86.075,86.198,86.601,86.198,87.245L86.198,87.245z"/>
   <path class="path" fill="#fff" d="M69.284,34.697c0,0.646-0.524,1.172-1.17,1.172H62.69c-0.646,0-1.171-0.522-1.171-1.172l0,0
    c0-0.646,0.525-1.169,1.171-1.169h5.424C68.762,33.528,69.284,34.053,69.284,34.697L69.284,34.697z"/>
   <path class="path" fill="#fff" d="M74.021,37.411c-0.646,0-1.172-0.366-1.172-0.817v-3.79c0-0.451,0.522-0.818,1.172-0.818l0,0
    c0.646,0,1.169,0.367,1.169,0.818v3.79C75.189,37.046,74.665,37.411,74.021,37.411L74.021,37.411z"/>
   <path class="path" fill="#fff" d="M86.198,34.697c0,0.646-0.524,1.172-1.17,1.172h-5.424c-0.646,0-1.171-0.522-1.171-1.172l0,0
    c0-0.646,0.525-1.169,1.171-1.169h5.424C85.676,33.528,86.198,34.053,86.198,34.697L86.198,34.697z"/>
   <path class="path" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M85.754,97.075H35.813
    c-2.115,0-3.676-0.537-4.77-1.645c-1.849-1.867-1.818-4.725-1.783-8.025c0.006-0.455,0.01-0.918,0.01-1.393
    c0-0.477-0.004-0.938-0.01-1.393c-0.035-3.305-0.065-6.16,1.783-8.025c1.094-1.105,2.654-1.646,4.77-1.646h49.941
    c2.115,0,3.676,0.539,4.771,1.646c1.849,1.869,1.816,4.723,1.781,8.025c-0.006,0.453-0.01,0.918-0.01,1.393
    c0,0.473,0.004,0.938,0.01,1.393c0.035,3.303,0.065,6.158-1.781,8.025C89.43,96.538,87.869,97.075,85.754,97.075z"/>
   <line class="path" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="60.783" y1="45.762" x2="60.783" y2="48.729"/>
   <line class="path" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="60.783" y1="71.651" x2="60.783" y2="74.354"/>
  </g>
  <h2>ATMService 1.0 0</h2>
  </svg>  
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema exacto? ¿Cómo "no funciona"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diferencias entre los dos SVG que tienes:

- Uno tiene `viewBox="0 0 121 122"` y el otro no tiene nada.
- Uno tiene un tamaño de 190x190 y el otro tiene un tamaño de 150x150
- Uno tiene un `stroke` de 3 en blanco y el otro de 1.1 en negro

Si le añadimos `viewBox` al que le falta, ponemos los dos con el mismo tamaño (190x190) y cambiamos el ancho del `stroke` a 3 en blanco para los dos, las animaciones se ven iguales:

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 0;
}

.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  animation: dash 5s linear alternate 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" y="200.69289" x="102.70579" height="190.90512" width="190.90512" enable-background="new 0 0 121 120.5" xml:space="preserve" viewBox="0 0 121 122">
  <g>
    <path d="M85.346,45.657H35.404c-2.115,0-3.675-0.538-4.769-1.644c-1.849-1.869-1.818-4.723-1.783-8.027
      c0.005-0.454,0.01-0.918,0.01-1.392s-0.005-0.938-0.01-1.391c-0.036-3.305-0.066-6.159,1.783-8.027
      c1.094-1.106,2.654-1.645,4.769-1.645h49.942c2.115,0,3.676,0.538,4.771,1.645c1.849,1.868,1.817,4.722,1.782,8.027
      c-0.006,0.454-0.01,0.918-0.01,1.391s0.004,0.938,0.01,1.392c0.035,3.304,0.065,6.158-1.782,8.027
      C89.021,45.119,87.461,45.657,85.346,45.657z M35.404,26.723c-1.218,0-2.037,0.228-2.5,0.697c-0.912,0.922-0.887,3.267-0.86,5.749
      c0.005,0.465,0.01,0.941,0.01,1.426s-0.005,0.96-0.01,1.426c-0.027,2.482-0.052,4.826,0.86,5.749
      c0.464,0.469,1.282,0.697,2.5,0.697h49.942c1.219,0,2.037-0.228,2.5-0.697c0.913-0.923,0.887-3.267,0.86-5.749
      c-0.005-0.466-0.011-0.942-0.011-1.426s0.006-0.96,0.011-1.426c0.026-2.482,0.053-4.826-0.86-5.749
      c-0.464-0.469-1.281-0.697-2.5-0.697H35.404z"/>
    <g>
      <path d="M68.876,35.125c0,0.646-0.524,1.17-1.17,1.17h-5.424c-0.646,0-1.171-0.524-1.171-1.17l0,0c0-0.646,0.525-1.17,1.171-1.17
        h5.424C68.354,33.956,68.876,34.48,68.876,35.125L68.876,35.125z"/>
      <path d="M67.706,36.935h-5.424c-0.997,0-1.809-0.812-1.809-1.809c0-0.997,0.812-1.808,1.809-1.808h5.424
        c0.997,0,1.81,0.811,1.81,1.808C69.516,36.123,68.703,36.935,67.706,36.935z M62.282,34.594c-0.294,0-0.532,0.239-0.532,0.532
        c0,0.293,0.238,0.532,0.532,0.532h5.424c0.293,0,0.532-0.239,0.532-0.532c0-0.293-0.239-0.532-0.532-0.532H62.282z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
      <path d="M74.727,36.35c0,0.617-0.5,1.117-1.117,1.117l0,0c-0.615,0-1.115-0.5-1.115-1.117v-2.021c0-0.617,0.5-1.117,1.115-1.117
        l0,0c0.617,0,1.117,0.5,1.117,1.117V36.35z"/>
      <path d="M73.609,38.104c-0.967,0-1.754-0.787-1.754-1.755v-2.021c0-0.968,0.787-1.755,1.754-1.755
        c0.968,0,1.756,0.787,1.756,1.755v2.021C75.365,37.317,74.578,38.104,73.609,38.104z M73.609,33.85
        c-0.264,0-0.479,0.215-0.479,0.479v2.021c0,0.264,0.216,0.479,0.479,0.479c0.265,0,0.479-0.215,0.479-0.479v-2.021
        C74.089,34.064,73.874,33.85,73.609,33.85z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
      <path d="M85.258,35.125c0,0.646-0.523,1.17-1.17,1.17h-4.361c-0.646,0-1.17-0.524-1.17-1.17l0,0c0-0.646,0.523-1.17,1.17-1.17
        h4.361C84.734,33.956,85.258,34.48,85.258,35.125L85.258,35.125z"/>
      <path d="M84.088,36.935h-4.361c-0.998,0-1.809-0.812-1.809-1.809c0-0.997,0.811-1.808,1.809-1.808h4.361
        c0.997,0,1.809,0.811,1.809,1.808C85.896,36.123,85.085,36.935,84.088,36.935z M79.727,34.594c-0.293,0-0.531,0.239-0.531,0.532
        c0,0.293,0.238,0.532,0.531,0.532h4.362c0.293,0,0.531-0.239,0.531-0.532c0-0.293-0.238-0.532-0.531-0.532H79.727z"/>
    </g>
    <path d="M85.346,71.547H35.404c-2.115,0-3.675-0.537-4.769-1.645c-1.849-1.869-1.818-4.724-1.783-8.025
      c0.005-0.455,0.01-0.92,0.01-1.393c0-0.475-0.005-0.938-0.01-1.394c-0.036-3.304-0.066-6.158,1.783-8.027
      c1.094-1.106,2.654-1.644,4.769-1.644h49.942c2.115,0,3.676,0.538,4.771,1.644c1.849,1.869,1.817,4.723,1.782,8.027
      c-0.006,0.454-0.01,0.918-0.01,1.394c0,0.473,0.004,0.938,0.01,1.393c0.035,3.303,0.065,6.156-1.782,8.025
      C89.021,71.01,87.461,71.547,85.346,71.547z M35.404,52.613c-1.218,0-2.037,0.228-2.5,0.697c-0.912,0.922-0.887,3.267-0.86,5.749
      c0.005,0.465,0.01,0.941,0.01,1.426c0,0.483-0.005,0.961-0.01,1.426c-0.027,2.481-0.052,4.826,0.86,5.75
      c0.464,0.469,1.282,0.696,2.5,0.696h49.942c1.219,0,2.037-0.229,2.5-0.696c0.913-0.922,0.887-3.269,0.86-5.75
      c-0.005-0.465-0.011-0.941-0.011-1.426s0.006-0.961,0.011-1.426c0.026-2.482,0.053-4.826-0.86-5.749
      c-0.464-0.469-1.281-0.697-2.5-0.697H35.404z"/>
    <g>
      <path d="M68.876,61.016c0,0.646-0.524,1.172-1.17,1.172h-5.424c-0.646,0-1.171-0.523-1.171-1.172l0,0
        c0-0.646,0.525-1.17,1.171-1.17h5.424C68.354,59.846,68.876,60.371,68.876,61.016L68.876,61.016z"/>
      <path d="M67.706,62.824h-5.424c-0.997,0-1.809-0.811-1.809-1.809c0-0.997,0.812-1.808,1.809-1.808h5.424
        c0.997,0,1.81,0.811,1.81,1.808C69.516,62.014,68.703,62.824,67.706,62.824z M62.282,60.484c-0.294,0-0.532,0.238-0.532,0.531
        c0,0.295,0.238,0.533,0.532,0.533h5.424c0.293,0,0.532-0.238,0.532-0.533c0-0.293-0.239-0.531-0.532-0.531H62.282z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
      <path d="M74.727,62.24c0,0.617-0.5,1.117-1.117,1.117l0,0c-0.615,0-1.115-0.5-1.115-1.117V60.22c0-0.617,0.5-1.117,1.115-1.117
        l0,0c0.617,0,1.117,0.5,1.117,1.117V62.24z"/>
      <path d="M73.609,63.994c-0.967,0-1.754-0.787-1.754-1.754v-2.021c0-0.968,0.787-1.755,1.754-1.755
        c0.968,0,1.756,0.787,1.756,1.755v2.021C75.365,63.209,74.578,63.994,73.609,63.994z M73.609,59.74
        c-0.264,0-0.479,0.215-0.479,0.479v2.021c0,0.264,0.216,0.479,0.479,0.479c0.265,0,0.479-0.215,0.479-0.479v-2.021
        C74.089,59.955,73.874,59.74,73.609,59.74z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
      <path d="M85.258,61.016c0,0.646-0.523,1.172-1.17,1.172h-4.361c-0.646,0-1.17-0.523-1.17-1.172l0,0c0-0.646,0.523-1.17,1.17-1.17
        h4.361C84.734,59.846,85.258,60.371,85.258,61.016L85.258,61.016z"/>
      <path d="M84.088,62.824h-4.361c-0.998,0-1.809-0.811-1.809-1.809c0-0.997,0.811-1.808,1.809-1.808h4.361
        c0.997,0,1.809,0.811,1.809,1.808C85.896,62.014,85.085,62.824,84.088,62.824z M79.727,60.484c-0.293,0-0.531,0.238-0.531,0.531
        c0,0.295,0.238,0.533,0.531,0.533h4.362c0.293,0,0.531-0.238,0.531-0.533c0-0.293-0.238-0.531-0.531-0.531H79.727z"/>
    </g>
    <path d="M85.346,96.971H35.404c-2.115,0-3.675-0.537-4.769-1.645c-1.849-1.867-1.818-4.724-1.783-8.025
      c0.005-0.455,0.01-0.918,0.01-1.393c0-0.476-0.005-0.938-0.01-1.392c-0.036-3.305-0.066-6.16,1.783-8.026
      c1.094-1.105,2.654-1.646,4.769-1.646h49.942c2.115,0,3.676,0.539,4.771,1.646c1.849,1.869,1.817,4.723,1.782,8.026
      c-0.006,0.453-0.01,0.918-0.01,1.392c0,0.473,0.004,0.938,0.01,1.393c0.035,3.303,0.065,6.158-1.782,8.025
      C89.021,96.434,87.461,96.971,85.346,96.971z M35.404,78.037c-1.218,0-2.037,0.229-2.5,0.697c-0.912,0.922-0.887,3.268-0.86,5.747
      c0.005,0.468,0.01,0.943,0.01,1.427s-0.005,0.961-0.01,1.428c-0.027,2.479-0.052,4.824,0.86,5.748
      c0.464,0.469,1.282,0.697,2.5,0.697h49.942c1.219,0,2.037-0.229,2.5-0.697c0.913-0.922,0.887-3.269,0.86-5.748
      c-0.005-0.467-0.011-0.941-0.011-1.428c0-0.484,0.006-0.959,0.011-1.427c0.026-2.479,0.053-4.825-0.86-5.747
      c-0.464-0.47-1.281-0.697-2.5-0.697H35.404z"/>
    <g>
      <path d="M68.876,86.439c0,0.646-0.524,1.17-1.17,1.17h-5.424c-0.646,0-1.171-0.522-1.171-1.17l0,0c0-0.645,0.525-1.17,1.171-1.17
        h5.424C68.354,85.27,68.876,85.795,68.876,86.439L68.876,86.439z"/>
      <path d="M67.706,88.25h-5.424c-0.997,0-1.809-0.813-1.809-1.812s0.812-1.807,1.809-1.807h5.424c0.997,0,1.81,0.812,1.81,1.807
        C69.516,87.438,68.703,88.25,67.706,88.25z M62.282,85.908c-0.294,0-0.532,0.238-0.532,0.531s0.238,0.533,0.532,0.533h5.424
        c0.293,0,0.532-0.24,0.532-0.533s-0.239-0.531-0.532-0.531H62.282z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
      <path d="M74.727,87.664c0,0.615-0.5,1.115-1.117,1.115l0,0c-0.615,0-1.115-0.5-1.115-1.115v-2.021c0-0.617,0.5-1.117,1.115-1.117
        l0,0c0.617,0,1.117,0.5,1.117,1.117V87.664z"/>
      <path d="M73.609,89.42c-0.967,0-1.754-0.787-1.754-1.756v-2.021c0-0.967,0.787-1.754,1.754-1.754c0.968,0,1.756,0.787,1.756,1.754
        v2.021C75.365,88.631,74.578,89.42,73.609,89.42z M73.609,85.164c-0.264,0-0.479,0.215-0.479,0.479v2.021
        c0,0.264,0.216,0.479,0.479,0.479c0.265,0,0.479-0.215,0.479-0.479v-2.021C74.089,85.379,73.874,85.164,73.609,85.164z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
      <path d="M85.258,86.439c0,0.646-0.523,1.17-1.17,1.17h-4.361c-0.646,0-1.17-0.522-1.17-1.17l0,0c0-0.645,0.523-1.17,1.17-1.17
        h4.361C84.734,85.27,85.258,85.795,85.258,86.439L85.258,86.439z"/>
      <path d="M84.088,88.25h-4.361c-0.998,0-1.809-0.813-1.809-1.812s0.811-1.807,1.809-1.807h4.361c0.997,0,1.809,0.812,1.809,1.807
        C85.896,87.438,85.085,88.25,84.088,88.25z M79.727,85.908c-0.293,0-0.531,0.238-0.531,0.531s0.238,0.533,0.531,0.533h4.362
        c0.293,0,0.531-0.24,0.531-0.533s-0.238-0.531-0.531-0.531H79.727z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
      <line fill="none" x1="60.375" y1="44.061" x2="60.375" y2="51.284"/>
      <rect x="58.779" y="44.061" width="3.192" height="7.223"/>
    </g>
    <g>
      <line fill="none" x1="60.375" y1="69.475" x2="60.375" y2="76.441"/>
      <rect x="58.779" y="69.475" width="3.192" height="6.967"/>
    </g>
  </g>
  <g>
    <path class="path" fill="#fff" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="0" d="M60.375,3.5c31.292,0,56.75,25.458,56.75,56.75c0,31.293-25.458,56.75-56.75,56.75S3.625,91.543,3.625,60.25
      C3.625,28.958,29.083,3.5,60.375,3.5 M60.375,0C27.1,0,0.125,26.976,0.125,60.25c0,33.275,26.975,60.25,60.25,60.25
      c33.275,0,60.25-26.975,60.25-60.25S93.65,0,60.375,0L60.375,0z"/>
  </g>
  </svg>


  <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" y="200.69289" x="102.70579" height="190.90512" width="190.90512" viewBox="0 0 121 122" enable-background="new 0 0 121 122" xml:space="preserve">
  <g>
    <g>
      <path d="M44.159,59.904c-4.657,0-8.446-3.79-8.446-8.446c0-4.658,3.789-8.447,8.446-8.447s8.447,3.79,8.447,8.447
        C52.606,56.114,48.816,59.904,44.159,59.904z M44.159,45.761c-3.141,0-5.696,2.555-5.696,5.696c0,3.141,2.555,5.696,5.696,5.696
        c3.141,0,5.696-2.555,5.696-5.696C49.855,48.316,47.3,45.761,44.159,45.761z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
      <path d="M32.272,51.916c-0.758,0-1.375-0.616-1.375-1.375c0-6.806,5.537-12.344,12.343-12.344c0.759,0,1.375,0.616,1.375,1.375
        c0,0.762-0.617,1.375-1.375,1.375c-5.291,0-9.593,4.304-9.593,9.594C33.648,51.299,33.033,51.916,32.272,51.916z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
      <path  class="path" fill="#fff" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2.4" stroke-miterlimit="0" d="M44.159,80.111c-2.875,0-5.215-2.43-5.215-5.417v-3.066c-1.884-0.485-3.678-1.23-5.356-2.222l-2.171,2.172
        c-1.047,1.047-2.428,1.624-3.889,1.624c-1.384,0-2.672-0.526-3.627-1.481c-2.033-2.033-1.968-5.405,0.143-7.517l2.17-2.171
        c-0.993-1.679-1.739-3.474-2.224-5.356h-3.064c-2.986,0-5.416-2.338-5.416-5.213s2.43-5.214,5.416-5.214h3.063
        c0.485-1.884,1.229-3.68,2.221-5.36l-2.166-2.166c-2.111-2.111-2.176-5.482-0.144-7.516c0.958-0.956,2.246-1.482,3.628-1.482
        c1.439,0,2.857,0.592,3.889,1.625l2.165,2.165c1.68-0.993,3.477-1.739,5.363-2.224v-3.059c0-2.986,2.34-5.416,5.215-5.416
        s5.214,2.43,5.214,5.416v3.059c1.886,0.485,3.682,1.23,5.361,2.223l2.165-2.164c1.049-1.049,2.43-1.625,3.891-1.625
        c1.383,0,2.671,0.526,3.626,1.481c2.032,2.034,1.966,5.405-0.144,7.517l-2.166,2.166c0.992,1.681,1.736,3.476,2.22,5.36h3.064
        c2.986,0,5.417,2.339,5.417,5.214s-2.43,5.213-5.417,5.213h-3.064c-0.486,1.884-1.23,3.679-2.224,5.357l2.169,2.17
        c2.113,2.111,2.175,5.483,0.144,7.517c-0.957,0.955-2.244,1.481-3.627,1.481c-1.46,0-2.842-0.577-3.891-1.624l-2.171-2.172
        c-1.678,0.992-3.473,1.735-5.355,2.22v3.069C49.374,77.682,47.034,80.111,44.159,80.111z M33.391,66.284
        c0.264,0,0.53,0.075,0.762,0.229c1.966,1.31,4.132,2.207,6.438,2.67c0.642,0.128,1.105,0.693,1.105,1.348v4.163
        c0,1.472,1.105,2.667,2.464,2.667s2.463-1.196,2.463-2.667v-4.165c0-0.655,0.463-1.219,1.105-1.348
        c2.306-0.462,4.471-1.358,6.437-2.668c0.545-0.362,1.271-0.29,1.735,0.172l2.946,2.947c0.994,0.993,2.71,1.062,3.628,0.143
        c0.959-0.96,0.895-2.587-0.144-3.627l-2.945-2.946c-0.464-0.463-0.536-1.19-0.172-1.734c1.311-1.965,2.21-4.131,2.671-6.438
        c0.129-0.643,0.693-1.105,1.349-1.105h4.16c1.472,0,2.666-1.105,2.666-2.463c0-1.357-1.196-2.464-2.666-2.464h-4.159
        c-0.656,0-1.221-0.462-1.35-1.106c-0.459-2.307-1.358-4.473-2.668-6.439c-0.363-0.546-0.292-1.272,0.172-1.735l2.942-2.941
        c1.039-1.04,1.102-2.667,0.143-3.627c-0.918-0.918-2.636-0.85-3.629,0.144l-2.939,2.94c-0.466,0.465-1.192,0.535-1.736,0.173
        c-1.966-1.311-4.132-2.209-6.44-2.672c-0.642-0.129-1.105-0.693-1.105-1.349v-4.155c0-1.47-1.104-2.666-2.463-2.666
        s-2.464,1.196-2.464,2.666v4.155c0,0.654-0.463,1.22-1.105,1.348c-2.309,0.462-4.478,1.361-6.443,2.673
        c-0.546,0.364-1.273,0.291-1.736-0.173l-2.939-2.94c-0.991-0.992-2.71-1.061-3.628-0.142c-0.959,0.96-0.896,2.587,0.143,3.626
        l2.941,2.942c0.463,0.463,0.535,1.188,0.172,1.734c-1.31,1.966-2.206,4.132-2.668,6.44c-0.128,0.643-0.693,1.106-1.348,1.106
        h-4.159c-1.471,0-2.666,1.105-2.666,2.463s1.196,2.464,2.666,2.464h4.162c0.655,0,1.219,0.461,1.348,1.104
        c0.462,2.306,1.361,4.472,2.67,6.438c0.363,0.544,0.292,1.271-0.172,1.734l-2.946,2.946c-1.039,1.04-1.103,2.667-0.143,3.627
        c0.918,0.917,2.635,0.85,3.627-0.144l2.946-2.946C32.685,66.419,33.037,66.284,33.391,66.284z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
      <path d="M83.252,84.289c-3.695,0-6.704-3.008-6.704-6.705c0-3.695,3.007-6.703,6.704-6.703c3.697,0,6.704,3.008,6.704,6.703
        C89.956,81.281,86.947,84.289,83.252,84.289z M83.252,73.633c-2.179,0-3.953,1.772-3.953,3.953c0,2.18,1.774,3.954,3.953,3.954
        s3.953-1.774,3.953-3.954C87.205,75.406,85.431,73.633,83.252,73.633z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
      <path class="path" fill="#fff" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2.4" stroke-miterlimit="0"  d="M83.252,99.514c-2.353,0-4.268-1.982-4.268-4.419v-2.053c-1.273-0.35-2.492-0.855-3.643-1.51l-1.45,1.451
        c-0.856,0.854-1.98,1.325-3.173,1.325c-1.132,0-2.188-0.432-2.971-1.217c-1.663-1.664-1.616-4.419,0.107-6.141l1.451-1.454
        c-0.654-1.148-1.161-2.368-1.511-3.642h-2.047c-2.438,0-4.42-1.914-4.42-4.267c0-2.353,1.982-4.269,4.42-4.269h2.045
        c0.352-1.273,0.856-2.493,1.511-3.644l-1.449-1.45c-1.722-1.722-1.77-4.476-0.109-6.141c0.785-0.786,1.843-1.218,2.974-1.218
        c1.192,0,2.317,0.471,3.172,1.323l1.445,1.447c1.152-0.655,2.373-1.162,3.647-1.511v-2.045c0-2.436,1.915-4.419,4.268-4.419
        c2.353,0,4.267,1.983,4.267,4.419v2.045c1.275,0.35,2.496,0.856,3.645,1.511l1.448-1.447c0.855-0.853,1.979-1.323,3.171-1.323
        c1.132,0,2.188,0.432,2.972,1.216c1.663,1.665,1.615,4.419-0.108,6.143l-1.447,1.448c0.655,1.15,1.161,2.37,1.51,3.645h2.046
        c2.438,0,4.42,1.915,4.42,4.267c0,2.354-1.983,4.269-4.42,4.269h-2.048c-0.351,1.273-0.856,2.493-1.511,3.642l1.45,1.451
        c1.724,1.725,1.772,4.48,0.108,6.143c-0.783,0.785-1.84,1.217-2.973,1.217c-1.19,0-2.317-0.47-3.17-1.324l-1.453-1.452
        c-1.15,0.654-2.368,1.159-3.641,1.509v2.053C87.519,97.532,85.604,99.514,83.252,99.514z M75.138,88.417
        c0.263,0,0.529,0.076,0.761,0.231c1.445,0.961,3.036,1.621,4.729,1.959c0.643,0.129,1.107,0.693,1.107,1.349v3.139
        c0,0.92,0.679,1.669,1.517,1.669c0.836,0,1.516-0.749,1.516-1.669v-3.139c0-0.656,0.463-1.22,1.105-1.349
        c1.694-0.339,3.284-0.999,4.727-1.959c0.548-0.363,1.271-0.289,1.735,0.172l2.22,2.22c0.622,0.621,1.69,0.67,2.254,0.107
        c0.59-0.592,0.542-1.603-0.108-2.255l-2.22-2.218c-0.465-0.463-0.536-1.19-0.172-1.735c0.961-1.442,1.623-3.034,1.964-4.73
        c0.129-0.643,0.693-1.104,1.348-1.104h3.134c0.921,0,1.67-0.68,1.67-1.518c0-0.836-0.75-1.517-1.67-1.517h-3.134
        c-0.655,0-1.221-0.463-1.348-1.105c-0.339-1.694-0.999-3.285-1.962-4.732c-0.362-0.545-0.29-1.271,0.173-1.734l2.215-2.215
        c0.651-0.652,0.7-1.663,0.108-2.254c-0.564-0.563-1.632-0.514-2.254,0.108l-2.214,2.215c-0.463,0.463-1.189,0.536-1.736,0.172
        c-1.443-0.961-3.034-1.622-4.731-1.962c-0.642-0.128-1.106-0.693-1.106-1.347v-3.133c0-0.92-0.679-1.668-1.515-1.668
        c-0.838,0-1.518,0.748-1.518,1.668v3.131c0,0.655-0.463,1.22-1.105,1.349c-1.696,0.341-3.289,1-4.734,1.962
        c-0.545,0.364-1.271,0.292-1.734-0.172l-2.215-2.215c-0.623-0.62-1.69-0.67-2.254-0.107c-0.592,0.591-0.543,1.603,0.107,2.253
        l2.217,2.217c0.463,0.461,0.535,1.189,0.173,1.734c-0.964,1.446-1.624,3.038-1.962,4.732c-0.127,0.642-0.693,1.105-1.349,1.105
        h-3.133c-0.92,0-1.668,0.68-1.668,1.516c0,0.836,0.749,1.517,1.668,1.517h3.135c0.656,0,1.221,0.462,1.35,1.105
        c0.339,1.692,0.998,3.285,1.962,4.73c0.362,0.545,0.291,1.271-0.172,1.734l-2.22,2.22c-0.649,0.65-0.698,1.663-0.106,2.253
        c0.561,0.563,1.631,0.513,2.253-0.107l2.22-2.22C74.431,88.556,74.783,88.417,75.138,88.417z"/>
    </g>
  </g>
  <g>
    <path class="path" fill="#fff" stroke="#000" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="2"  d="M60.343,4.414c31.292,0,56.75,25.458,56.75,56.75s-25.458,56.75-56.75,56.75s-56.75-25.458-56.75-56.75
      S29.051,4.414,60.343,4.414 M60.343,0.914c-33.275,0-60.25,26.975-60.25,60.25c0,33.275,26.975,60.25,60.25,60.25
      s60.25-26.975,60.25-60.25C120.593,27.889,93.618,0.914,60.343,0.914L60.343,0.914z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Perfecto alvaro ahi estuve probado, una consulta mas: como debería hacer para que por ejemplo los engranajes del ejemplo de la derecha tbn hicieran el mismo efecto que el circulo?

Comment: porque si miras tiene una animación pero redibuja sobre su misma forma yo le intente poner en blanco el stroke pero no me funciono

Comment: @MarianoAndresFranco Puedes ponerle el fondo blanco con la línea negra (ahora mismo tiene el fondo negro con la línea negra). De ese modo se vería algo "parecido" a lo del círculo exterior (tendrías que hacer el `stroke` más ancho, como de 2.4 o 2.5 en lugar de 1.1).

Comment: Bien! voy a probar entonces muchas gracias alvaro

Comment: Sabes que no me salio alvaro

Comment: @MarianoAndresFranco actualicé la respuesta para que se vea la animación de los engranajes mejor. Les puse un fondo blanco y aumenté el stroke a 2.4

Comment: Buenisimo, muchas gracias Alvaro

Comment: Una ultima consulta Alvaro, edite el codigo nuevamente, sabes si existe algun forma de ponerle un stop a la animacion de los iconos? osea q se animan por una unica ves. osea cada ves que entrarias a la pagina. como el ejemplo este https://sandbox.developerhub.citi.com/

Comment: @MarianoAndresFranco Eso se hace con CSS, ahora mismo la animación le tienes puesto `infinite` para que se reproduzca de manera infinita, cambia ese `infinite` por `1` y ya sólo se ejecutará una vez. Además, querrás poner `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`  para que al terminar se quede en el estado final y no se rebobine.

Comment: Genial!! muchas gracias Alvaro